# Why does 2-pyridone with chlorine gives 3,5-dichloro-2-pyridone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds

Why does 2-pyridone react with chlorine to give 3,5-dichloro-2-pyridone? I thought that 2-pyridone is resistant and will yield only 5-chloro-2-pyridone or even a combination with 3-chloro-2-pyridone

Comment: resistant does not mean it does not react